# Event Receiver, Before and After properties

Tags: development, event-receivers, versioning

In an event receiver, Item Was Updated. I want to Compare the Moderation status on ListItems to perform some functionality.This is just some of the code.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["DocLib"];
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemID);

var moderationStatus = item["_ModerationStatus"] as string;

if(moderationStatus == SPModerationStatusType.Approve.ToString())
   //Do stuff
```

So I should be able to get the values from this to make the comparison in a later stage:

```
string beforeStatus = properties.BeforeProperties["_ModerationStatus"] as string;
string afterStatus = properties.AfterProperties["_ModerationStatus"] as string;
```

In Document Libraries we know that:

- BeforeProperties = Original Value.
- AfterProperties = Changed Value.

But beforeStatus and afterStatus is null.

Does someone have any tips of other ways to Compare the values? I have even tried to take get the value form "ItemUptading" to get the value before it updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem but...

> For documents, Before and After properties are guaranteed for post
>   events, such as ItemUpdated, but Before properties are **not available**
>   for post events **on list items**

Reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463479.aspx

If this is your scenario you may want to use `properties.ListItem` and use that to compare the values. This article may help you further... http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: So the problem lies with the accessing of the parameter. I have to use the "vti_" named parameters for it to work for title, but i can't use the vti_doclibmodstat to access the ModerationStatus. Have any toughts?
 - title --> vti_title
 - _ModerationStatus --> vti_doclibmodstat

Answer (score 2):

To get the functionality as with before and after properties and if() statments with the same result as the code does down bellow.

*So to answer my question, one of the problems with Before and After properties with versioning is that it's not 100% complete. In some cases the before value (of moderationStatus) is null, when it before value is 2 or pending it's OK, but when it's 3 or draft the before value is null.. just one example.*

This might help someone who's struggling with the same issue i had.

**The Code:**

```
if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"] != null)
        {
            var after = (SPModerationStatusType)int.Parse(properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"].ToString());
            switch (properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation.Status)
            {
                case SPModerationStatusType.Approved:
                    switch (after)
                    {
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Draft:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Pending:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case SPModerationStatusType.Denied:
                    switch (after)
                    {
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Draft:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Pending:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case SPModerationStatusType.Draft:
                    switch (after)
                    {
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Draft:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Pending:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case SPModerationStatusType.Pending:
                    switch (after)
                    {
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Approved:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Denied:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Draft:
                            break;
                        case SPModerationStatusType.Pending:
                            //hej
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar but more specific case. Needed to do some stuff for the first (and only the first) time document was approved. Here is what I did. Hope it helps someone.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"] != null)
        {
            SPModerationStatusType after = (SPModerationStatusType)int.Parse(properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"].ToString());

            if (!properties.ListItem.HasPublishedVersion
                 && after == SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
            {
             ...
```

Answer (score -1):

1. use internal names for columns to get the after properties in item updating event.
2. to get before properties use properties.listitem

http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/09/synchronous-add-list-event-itemadding.html